# Restricting number of characters in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Firstly, being extremely honest I have minimal knowledge of Javascript and jQuery.

I have been working on a webite and have used a smart form plugin to create an order form. It has an option to add in javascript. I have created one to restrict date selection on a datepicker tool.

However I'm having trouble with trying to restrict the number of characters to 11 in a particular field. I would also like to restrict it to only numbers, letters and /.

It provides me with the below code to edit and use.

```
(function(){
    var javaObject = {
        AfterFormLoaded: function(jQueryFormReference) {},
        BeforeFormSubmit: function(formData, jQueryFormReference) {}
    };
    return javaObject;    
})
```

If anyone is able to help or point me in the right direct it would be a massive help.

Comment: You can directly use the max and minlength property attribute of html input fields. No need to add separate script for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the default attributes of HTML input fields.

> Max length and
>   Min length

Following is the example of code to make use of the attributes.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="test field" />
```

There is no need to add Javascript explicitly unless required.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Javascript for this one. Just use the [maxlength](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) property (html). For example, if you want a text input with max of 10 chars:

```
<input type="text" name="my_text" maxlength="10">
```